# htacces para nginx

Tags: htaccess, nginx, url-amigável

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1

Options -Indexes
```

Preciso converter essa regra em `htaccess` para `nginx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No nginx use o `try_files` e ao invés da variável `$_GET['url']` use `REQUEST_URI`

nginx.conf deve ficar algo como:

```
location / {
    autoindex on;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Um exemplo para pegar o PATH (baseado em um framework que fiz https://github.com/inphinit/framework/blob/master/src/Utils.php#L62):

```php
function UrlPath()
{
    static $pathInfo;

    if ($pathInfo !== null) {
        return $pathInfo;
    }

    $sname  = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $reqUri = empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? null :
                preg_replace('#\?(.*)$#', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $pathInfo = rtrim(strtr(dirname($sname), '\\', '/'), '/');

    $pathInfo = substr(urldecode($reqUri), strlen($pathInfo) + 1);

    $pathInfo = '/' . ($pathInfo === false ? '' : $pathInfo);

    return $pathInfo;
}
```

Para usar basta chamar assim:

```php
echo UrlPath();
```

Ao invés de:

```php
echo $_GET['url'];
```

Desta maneira com a função `UrlPath` não irá afetar as variáveis GET, se precisar portar o `try_files` para apache faça assim:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```